# How to combine StudentProfileID and Date Today as a customID on Create Method in C# MVC5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

How can I make a custom RegNo combining the StudentProfileID and DateToday?

StudentProfileID- is the primary key automatically generated on Create Method

 Date Today- format: 031415

Sample Code of Create Method

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="StudentProfileID,RegNo,EnrollmentDate,LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,Address,ContactNo,MaritalStatus,Birthdate,Birthplace,Age,PositionRank,Years,PRC,SBOOK,MMAP,PPORT,SRC,TraineeType,EndorsedBy,EmergencyPerson,EmergencyAddress,EmergencyContactNo,EmergencyRelationship")] StudentProfile studentprofile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.StudentProfile.Add(studentprofile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(studentprofile);
    }
```

I followed this article in creating the student profile
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/869986/CRUD-operation-with-Entity-Framework-Code-First

I'll appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After db.savechanges(); we will get the sudentProfileId as follow

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.StudentProfile.Add(studentprofile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int studentId = studentprofile.StudentId;
            string custRegNo = studetId.toString()+ DateTime.Now;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```